# How to open multiple tabs in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs

"windows.open()" works for Firefox but I can't get it to work on Chrome; any workarounds?

Comment: Can you provide some more code? PS: `window.open()` (instead of `windows.open()`) does work in Chrome

Comment: have you tried `target="_blank"` attribute?

Comment: @jonju that is assuming he is using something like an `<a>` element, this could just be in a function somewhere

Comment: this is what I was talking  about window.open("url", "_blank"); not `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this's what you are looking for

```
window.open("url","_blank");
```